# Show that if $x_n \to x$ then $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Show that if $x_n \to x$ then $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$ I have been stuck on this for a while. I tried $$|\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x}| = \frac{|x_n - x|}{|\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}|},$$ and then I at least can get the top to be as small as I want, so I have $$\frac{\epsilon}{|\sqrt{x+\epsilon} + \sqrt{x}|},$$ but I get stuck here at choosing the N, and I don't know if my first step in breaking down the absolute value is legitimate. Please help.

Comment: If you separate the case $x=0$ from $x\ne 0$ you can prove the later with your method and the former directly.

Comment: You might be interested in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67032/) which asks how to prove that $x^{1/n}$ is continuous for all $n$ and all $x >0$. In particular, my answer there explains a similar idea as yours.

Comment: Since $|ab| = |a||b|$ I see no reason why we could not have just used the difference of squares to find that
$|\sqrt x_n - \sqrt x| \leq |\sqrt x_n + \sqrt x||\sqrt x_n - \sqrt x| = |x_n -x| \lt \epsilon$

Answer (score 7):

1. You want to treat the case $x=0$ separately.
2. When $x\neq 0$, the identity you used is the way to go. Next use $\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}\geq \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $(x_n)\rightarrow x$, then for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$, we have,
$$|x_n-x|<\epsilon \sqrt{x} \hspace{10pt} \text{when}\hspace{10pt} n\geq N$$
This implies 
$$\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}}<\epsilon \hspace{10pt} \text{when}\hspace{10pt} n\geq N$$
Notice,
\begin{align*}
|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|&=|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|\left(\frac{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\right)\\
&=\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&\leq  \frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}} 
\end{align*}
So, when $n\geq N$,
$$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|\leq\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}}<\epsilon $$
Hence, $(\sqrt{x_n})\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$.