# If sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, prove that $\sqrt x_n$ converges to $\sqrt x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

If sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, prove that $\sqrt x_n$ converges to c.
I know I have to estimate

$| \sqrt x_n - \sqrt x |$. But I cannot start. Thanks

Comment: Similar question: [Show that if $x_n \to x$ then $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99345/show-that-if-x-n-to-x-then-sqrtx-n-to-sqrtx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** :
 
If your $x$ is zero, it is trivial. 
Else, note that
$$|\sqrt a-\sqrt b|=\frac{|a-b|}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$$
So does $(\sqrt x_n+\sqrt x)$ have a lower limit here?

Comment: can you elaborate on how to estimate denominator

Comment: @K.Dutta If $x\ne0$ then $$\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x \ge \sqrt x=c$$ Besides, this works for all $n\in\mathbb N^{+}$, so $n$ doesn't have to be "sufficiently large". And the absolute value symbol in the denominator is also unnecessary. (I've edited my answer for these issues)

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a continuous function and $\{a_n\}$ a sequence that converges to a limit $c$ , it is a useful fact that $\{f(a_n) \}$ converges to $f(c)$.

You should prove this, as it comes up a lot.  Besides, it'll be easier to prove the more general case, and then apply it to this specific problem.